# Why does using require.ensure in two different ways cause code splitting to fail

Tags: javascript, webpack, code-splitting

**Code splitting using webpack5's default configuration**

```js
// chunk1.js

export const a = 'xxx'
```

```js
// index.js
 
// code splitting success 
require.ensure(
  [],
  (require) => {
    const mod = require('./chunk1')
    mod.default
  },
  'chunk1'
)
```

**output files:**

- main.js
- chunk1.js

```js
// code splitting fail 
require.ensure(
  [],
  (require) => {
    require('./chunk1').default
  },
  'chunk1'
)
```

**output files:**

- main.js (this file include chunk1.js)

Why does `require('./chunk1').default` cause code splitting to fail